# Как вытащить из List элемент

Tags: java, list

Подскажите пожалуйста как вытащить из List элемент типа byte ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Действительно считаете, что такие вопросы уместно задавать в интернете, а не искать ответы в книгах?

Comment: В списке объекты класса FilesPdf. Посмотрите методы этого класса.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вытащить элемент по индексу `myList.get(index)`.

Если необходимо вытащить элемент по какому-то условию используйте `Stream API`.